# How much of a PDA can a program control

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, account, anchor-lang

How much of a PDA is under the control of its owner program? For example, could the program block the account from signing certain instructions on transactions? Or could the program add a fee to every transaction a PDA signs? Whats the limit of control over PDAs and how can you access all features of them on Anchor

Answer (score 1):

a PDA is limited to how much the program offers in controllability.

To elaborate. Let's say your program has a single instruction `initialize` that initializes a pda account. In that case, your program cannot change the PDA after it's initialized.

You add an `update` instruction that updates the PDA data to a certain way. This will offer you the ability to use that instruction to update it. But only in **that** certain way.

This is great for security because you don't have to worry that a pda might be initialized in a malicious way or it has unvalid data. The pda will only follow the rules of the program. It cannot be updated outside of the program.

Answer (score 1):

PDA can store DATA and also sign for CPI(Cross program Invocations) for example you have an escrow and you have created a tokenAccount whose authority is a PDA then only the PDA can control the transfer of tokens from that TokenAccount.

Answer (score 1):

A program only has explicit signing authority over its PDAs, so its control is limited to everything that it can sign.

After that, if your program creates an account at a PDA, then it can control that account as much as any other account that it owns.

Feel free to read through the official documentation on program-derived addresses at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-derived-addresses and on account ownership at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#ownership-and-assignment-to-programs